# SSE Stream Update Interval (in Nchan)

Tags: nginx, events, server-sent-events, nchan

I am using Nchan/Nginx as SSE server, and I know that every roughly 3 seconds it sends an update from the server to a client. I would like to know how to change that interval time from 3 to something else on the server side?